# Inject automapper with Autofac in each Controller class

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, automapper, autofac

I want to inject the automapper in other layes of the application. I have read other posts and articles but I can't manage to figure out how to apply them. I am new to automapping and IoC. This is what I've tried by now. What can I change so that I automapper would be injected in controller and other layers?

```
public class AutomapperConfig
{
    public MapperConfiguration Config { get; set; }
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<CustomerViewModel, CustomerBusinessModel>().ReverseMap();
            ...
        }
}

public static IContainer BuildContainer()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
    ....
    return builder.Build();
}

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public IContainer _container;
    protected void Application_Start()
    {  ...
       _container = AutofacConfig.BuildContainer();
       DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(_container));
    }
}

public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBusinessLogic<CustomerBusinessModel> _customerBl;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public CustomersController (IBusinessLogic<CustomerBusinessModel> customer, AutomapperConfig automapper)
    {
        _customerBl= customer;
        mapper = automapper.Config.CreateMapper();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
builder.Register(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
     {
        cfg.CreateMap<CustomerViewModel, CustomerBusinessModel>().ReverseMap();
        ...
     })
     .AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance();

builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IConfigurationProvider>().CreateMapper())
    .As<IMapper>();
```

`CustomerController.cs`

```
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBusinessLogic<CustomerBusinessModel> _customerBl;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CustomersController (IBusinessLogic<CustomerBusinessModel> customer, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _customerBl= customer;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
```